# FINDING total number of paths using backtracking

Tags: recursion, path, grid, backtracking

### I'm trying to count total paths in a 20x20 grid(ProjectEuler #15) using backtracking.I've played around with it but the answer is always None. Any help would be appreciated(I know it can be solved using recursion or memoization but i want to solve it using backtracking)

```
def isvalid(maze,n,x,y):
    if x<0 or y<0 or x>n or y>n :
        return False
    else: return True

def countPaths(maze,x,y,n,used,count):
    if x==n-1 or y==n-1:
        count+=1
        return
    if isvalid(maze,n,x,y):
        used[x][y]=True
        if (x+1<n and used[x+1][y]==False):
            countPaths(maze,x+1,y,n,used,count)
        if (x-1>0 and used[x-1][y]==False):
            countPaths(maze,x-1,y,n,used,count)
        if (y+1<n and used[x][y+1]==False):
            countPaths(maze,x,y+1,n,used,count)
        if (y-1>0 and used[x][y-1]==False):
            countPaths(maze,x,y-1,n,used,count)
        used[x][y]=False
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in the base case, you are only returning 1 whenever end of row or column occurs it would yield wrong answer.
You should increment a counter signifying the number of times you are able to reach the final [n-1][n-1] i.e rightmost bottom cell.

```
bool isValid(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= n || y < 0 || y >= n)
        return false;
    return true;
}
void countPaths(int x, int y)
{
    // cout << x << y << endl;
    if (x == n - 1 && y == n - 1)
    {
        paths++;
        return;
    }

    if (isValid(x, y))
    {
        visited[x][y] = true;
        countPaths(x, y + 1);
        countPaths(x + 1, y);
    }

    return;
}
```

Keeping paths & visited as global variables , I implemented the above approach.

```
For n=2 (1+1): 2
For n=3 (2+1): 6
For n=4 (3+1): 20
For n=5 (4+1): 70
```

however, this approach would not be viable for n=20.
I would suggest trying Dynamic Programming as it would simplify the process!

Comment: i have modified it adding and did what you said but still doesnt work